# path is not reading unless it is in order

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i added 2 primery keys to 2 paths A and B in one html page and added paths to url, each i gave {% url 'name' pk.id %} to move to defrent pages but when i click the url B  it shows page not found so i put the path B to first then it works but the the Path A is not working

```
   path('<int:prgm_id>/', views.program, name='program'),
path('<int:services_id>/', views.details, name='details')
```

]``

```
   <a href="{% url 'program' prgm.id %}">
             <div id="prgm" style="width:50%">

  <a href="{% url 'details' services.id %}">
              <div class="box wow ">
                  <div class="col-xs-2" id=
```

Answer (score 3):

It is perfect sensical that both will trigger the `program` view. Both `{% url …%}`s will encode a url that looks like `42/` for example. So that means that if the browser later visits that url, then Django will pick the first view that matches. Note that the context of the name of the view is "gone". Indeed, the rendered HTTP response only contains a URL, and not how that URL was generated.

In general the paths you define should *not overlap*. That means that no path generated by the first `path(..)`, should be path that can be generated by the latter `path(..)` call and vice-versa.

You can resolve the ambiguity for example with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:prgm_id>/', views.program, name='program'),
    path('<int:services_id>/details/', views.details, name='details')
]
```